# Fit the range in sql

Tags: sql

I have simple database:

```
PostcodeFrom | PostcodeTo
00000        | 99999 
90210        | 95102
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE PostcodeFrom <= '91000' AND PostcodeTo >= '91000'
```

In results there is two rows. I want to get only better row (from 90210 to 95102). But in this same query I want to get one result for e.g. '12345'.

I hope there is clearly.

Could you help me?

Comment: how doe sthis add up? `WHERE PostcodeFrom <= '91000' AND PostcodeTo >= '91000'`  ??

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you want one result, try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE PostcodeFrom <= '91000' AND PostcodeTo >= '91000'
ORDER BY (case when PostcodeFrom = '0000' then 1 else 0 end)
LIMIT 1;
```

This uses `limit`.  Some databases might use `select top 1` or `where rownum = 1` or `fetch first 1 rows only`.